# How to add arrows on full screen slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, slider

I recently completed a website for a photography friend and he came back to me saying that the sliders on his project pages were hard to use and he would like arrows, whenever I have tried adding arrows into it I've found the Navigation pushes the arrows out of view, I was wondering if anyone knows of a way of fixing this.

Please see the link below to the page. Thank you in advance.

[Daniels Website](http://www.danielgaskell.co.uk/travel.html)

Comment: Please provide a jsfidlle of what you have tried yet?

Comment: Your problem is make something when the user click on the arrow or display the arrow in the middle of screen, left and right ?

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked uses Swiper, which is a framework for sliders. According to the [Getting Started](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/), you need to add two arrows, which your friend seems to have commented out. Since your site has jQuery, you also need to initialize it within the document.ready event. Try putting the code within the event like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready  
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        loop: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: 7000,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        effect: 'fade'
    })
  });
```